# css / html text on text mouseover shortcode wrap

Tags: html, css

I have an area on a web page filled with a block text and wanted to have another block text on mouseover in the same place, the same font size , etc, just a different message. Is there any possibility to achieve this effect using CSS/ HTML ? I know that this can be possible using images but I am interested to have more control to the font type and to have better display quality.

LE: Based on below answer of Paulie_D and below mentioned Reece George code , I am trying to wrap a shortcode like this :

```
<div class="parent">
<h1 id="h1">[slabtext]
[slab]Fit text[/slab]
[slab]Typography[/slab]
[slab]Made easy[/slab]
[slab]use a WordPress shortcode[/slab]
[/slabtext]</h1>
<div class="child">
<h1 id="h1">[slabtext]
[slab]hover two[/slab]
[slab]Typography[/slab]
[slab]Made easy[/slab]
[slab]look mom no hands[/slab]
[/slabtext]</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
h1
            {
            text-align:left;
            font-family:'LeagueGothicRegular', "Impact", Charcoal, Arial Black, Gadget, Sans serif;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            line-height:1;
            color:#222;
            font-size:300%;
            /* Remember to set the correct font weight if using fontface */
            font-weight:normal;
            }
        /* Smaller font-size for the side-by-side demo */
        .col-1 h1,
        .col-2 h1
            {
            font-size: 32px;
            }


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parent {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 25px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  display: none;
}
.parent:hover .child {
  display: block;
}
p {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

The result is pretty strange and not so sure how can I receive the same effect on child hover too (slabtext fit on the window).The result :

[image: hover 1]

[image: hover 2]

any thoughts please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish the containing div to remain the same size, there are some limitations.

The second text block would have to be shorter than the first.

This method is similar to the one by Tim Osadchiy but the child div is positioned to cover the parent (this requires a background color to hide the underlying text.)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parent {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 25px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  display: none;
}
.parent:hover .child {
  display: block;
}
p {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet quod numquam illum perferendis deserunt vel quia voluptas dolorem animi dignissimos quisquam sint reiciendis soluta impedit voluptates ipsam iste? Iure alias dolore doloremque eum totam
    perspiciatis commodi illo porro consequatur placeat et aspernatur rerum omnis harum in odit nam cumque ducimus!</p>
  <div class="child">
    <p>Iure alias dolore doloremque eum totam perspiciatis commodi illo porro consequatur placeat et aspernatur rerum omnis harum in odit nam cumque ducimus!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you all ! actually, I am trying to wrap Reece George code into mouseover thing.The last solution it looks like it could be an answer but not so sure why it doesn't work fine. [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myavEw) .any thoughts ? The child doesn't work as expecting ...

Comment: LE: the solution came after I’ve made these changes in the css :
`.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  display: block;
}
.parent:hover .child {
  display: none;
}`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with CSS/ HTML:

```css
#block .hover {
  display: none;
}

#block:hover .hover {
  display: inline;
}

#block:hover .no-hover {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  <span class="no-hover">
    Initial text
  </span>
  <span class="hover">
    Text with mouseover
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that this solution will affect the size of the containing div which may not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach.

```css
.message {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.message::before {
  content: 'Get Messages';
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  background: darkorange;
}
.message:hover::before {
  content: 'New Message!';
  background: darkorange;
}
```

```html
<div class='message'>Message</div>
```

Comment: Pseudo elements should not be used to contain **actual content**.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes. I agree. He wasn't being very specific though.

Comment: Well "block of text" would indicate a fairly large amount but if the requirement is for an'indicator' of some kind then the might be one solution.